# Kotlin setters/getters metaprogramming question

Tags: kotlin

I was wondering if there is a clever way to automatically generate setters/getters of a child class within the parent class with metaprogramming, like that :

```
open class TableClass {
    protected val t: MutableMap<String,Any> = mutableMapOf()
    fun attribute (k:String,v:Any) {
        t[k] = v
    }
}

class Coordinates () : TableClass() {
    //Automatically generate that through metaprogramming in the parent class
    var x : Int
        get() = t["x"] as Int
        set(v)  { this.attribute ( "x", v ) }
    var y : Int // ...
}
```

Thank you for your attention !

Comment: @mahan I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I just want to automate the creation of getters and setters in the child class for any created attribute. The parent class should be unaware of possible child classes at its creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to Python, which I believe you reference here, Kotlin is a strongly typed language, so it is not possible to generate properties or fields dynamically.

You can use [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) to at least make it a little more "dynamic":

```
class Coordinates () : TableClass() {
    var x : Int by t
    var y : Int by t
}
```

The reason why it works is because your are lucky ;-) Kotlin automatically provides a way to delegate properties to `Map<String,Any>`. But you still have to declare all required properties and delegate them. You can also implement your own property delegators, other than maps.

Other than that, you can use annotation processing to automatically generate the Kotlin source code while compiling, but this is much longer story and this is probably not what you really want.

Comment: Delegated properties will do, thank you !